# file moved when system writing information in file C ++

Tags: c++, logging, scheduler

I am not sure if this is even a valid question. I am not a master at understanding the workings of system. One of my program writes logs to a text file. Another email program runs on scheduler and emails and archives the log file if found in the folder.
 My question is, If at any given instant if the first program is writing information into the file and at the same time email scheduler runs what will happen? Will the email program be able to mail the file and archive it? If Yes, will the earlier program writing the file crash? How to handle this scenario without crashing either programs?

Comment: You need to synchronize the programs. Check Producer consumer problem 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: That entirely depends on your OS and the way you opened the file (e.g. locking etc.)

Comment: Use `fcntl()` and lock the file and release when purpose is fulfilled. like lock when writing and release when written.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, your setup will lead to some kind of trouble.

I think the simplest solution would be to have the program that writes the log file do this e.g. 5 minutes before the emailer/archiver is scheduled to run:

- start a new file for logging
- copy or rename the old file to the file that the emailer/archiver uses.

Comment: What if the logging program is a real time event based program?

Comment: What kind of trouble do you think might occur?

Comment: @user2388323: Especially if it is a real time program it is important that it is not interfered with by the archiving program. You can write the logging program so that it switches files at certain times. That way the file that is being written to is never the same as the one being archived.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious: If the file is not locked, deleting or moving it while it is being written to could cause crashes. Or at best it could cause partial log messages to be written. If the file is locked by one program or the other, it could cause the other program to fail if it is not designed to tolerate not being able to access the file.